# Using select2 on custom django forms and model forms

Tags: python, django

While reading the documentation of https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2, there is a note: "Django's admin comes with builtin support for Select2 since version 2.0 via the autocomplete_fields feature."

I was able to enable autocomplete_fields for my admin site forms.

The question is, is there any built-in functionality for custom and model forms where I need not install any third-party libraries?

Is there any way I can leverage already included select2 functionality (for admin site) for model forms?

I tried searching the same on google but could not find any documentation.

This code is irrelevant but I thought my question should have some code so.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Market(models.Model):
    CHOICES = [
        ('IN', 'India'),
        ('US', 'United States'),
        ('EP', 'Europe'),
        ('JP', 'Japan')
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                            choices=CHOICES,
                            blank=True,
                            unique=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    markets = models.ManyToManyField(Market)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin


class MarketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']

class ProductAdmin(MarkdownxModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['market']
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm


class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['markets']
```

Comment: built-in `autocomplete_fields` works with related fields (FK and M2M fields)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you help me with my above code on how I can use FK or M2M fields?